# Search YouTrack independant of installation language

Tags: internationalization, youtrack, youtrack-api

I'm writing a tool, that fetches the issues on which a user has spent some time within the last week, and displays the spent time for each day and issue as a summary, so that the user knows, where he might have forgotten to book time.

In YouTrack 2018.2 you can search for Issues by `work date` which is exactly what I want. Unfortunately the query `work date: {Last Week}` only works in a YouTrack instance that has been set to english. But I also need to be able to handle a german instance. The query there would have to be `Arbeitsdatum: {Last Week}`

The `{Last Week}` placeholders seems to be working, even without localization but the field name seems to be different, depending on the installation language.

Is there any generic field name I can use for that? Or at least an API call that allows me to determine the proper fieldname?

If not: is there a List of the field names somewhere publicly available, so that I can provide a mapping depending on the YouTrack installation language?

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the current 2018.2 YouTrack version. Actually the search should always work by the english field names.

An issue has been openened at the youtrack bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-47943